# Are there any risks about switching to a non-fluoride toothpaste?

Tags: dentistry, risks, toothpaste, fluoride

Assuming I am not on any prescribed toothpaste and only toothpaste I been using are conventional toothpaste bought over the counter with fluoride. Also, assume I have a good brushing and flossing habit.

Would there be any risks or effects by switching to a toothpaste that does not contain fluoride?

Answer (score 3):

If all the rest is the same, **your risk of caries would increase by 25%** [Source: Cochrane Syst Review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12535435).

Comment: The study doesnt tell what the "placebo" "nonfluoride toothpaste" is,at least in it's abstract.They could have taken natural ingredients that are not doing anything and then claim fluoride is better. Looks like a deeply biased study.

That's like proving calcium fluoride has no important concerns to health effect if it stays insoluble, but then use Sodium Fluoride or Fluorosilicic in toothpaste or tap water.